# How to locate the element using Selenium and xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How to locate the element:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Area / Locality" class="" value="">
```

I tried:

```
//input[@placeholder='Enter Area / Locality']
```

but it is not working.

I want to send keys at this placeholder from selenium code.

Comment: Can you please add the error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code trial. As an alternative you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
//input[@placeholder=\"Enter Area / Locality\"]"
```

---

However, ideally as it is an `<input>` element and you want to invoke `click()` on it, you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Enter Area / Locality']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter Area / Locality']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, I want to pass some value to this placeholder. BBut it is still not working.